# How to develop an Excel Macro that contains regular expressions so it will work in Windows and Mac

Tags: regex, excel, vba, macos

I have developed an Excel 2010 VBA Macro that makes use of `VBScript.RegExp`.  One of my users is apparently using Excel Mac 2011, which supports VBA, but no `VBScript.RegExp`.

I have seen several posts that mention it is possible to create your own RegEx functions using `AppleScript` that could be called by the VBA Macro.  However, it seems as though there would have to be a Mac version of the Excel file and a Windows version.  This is less than ideal.

Is there another way to implement regular expressions in VBA that would be compatible with both Windows and Mac?

Comment: You can use an `If-Endif` to check for the OS and then decide whether you want to run RegExp or AppleScript. In such a scenario, I would recommend using Late Binding with RegExp for Windows. Also you might want to read this ( http://www.computerworld.com.au/article/304149/10_applescripts_make_love_your_mac_even_more_/ ) which says `AppleScript is not particularly well suited for a lot of text manipulation. There's no built-in support for regular expressions; there's not even a simple search-and-replace function as part of core AppleScript.`

Comment: That's comment is only true with vanilla AppleScript, which anyone who uses AppleScript to do anything but `beep` doesn't use. Download [Satimage.osax](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/downloads/downloads_companion_osaxen.html) and use the `change` command for full RegEx support in a variety of flavors.

Comment: I'd be curious to know how you solved this, if you have.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find a solution, only a workaround.  I just replaced my regular expressions with a series of `Replace` calls.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no solution for this has yet been found — the current workaround is to simply replace regular expressions with a series of `Replace` calls (or other required operation).

Comment: @Aesthir's comment seems worth a try, the day `Replace` just won't do anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I hit this problem trying to use the regexp library when trying to strip html tags from a cell.

I know this wasn't noted within the question as the desired use but, in case it is or future visitors are trying to replace a regex function to remove HTML from tags within a cell within Mac Excel 2011, this user defined function will work. Apologies to the original author, i found it only but can no longer find the source i'm afraid.

```
Public Function StripHTML(zDataIn As String) As String

  Dim iStart As Integer
  Dim iEnd   As Integer
  Dim iLen   As Integer

  Do While InStr(zDataIn, "<") > 0
    iStart = InStr(zDataIn, "<")
    iEnd = InStr(iStart, zDataIn, ">")
    iLen = Len(zDataIn)
    If iStart = 1 Then
      zDataIn = Right(zDataIn, iLen - iEnd)
    Else
      If iLen = iEnd Then
        zDataIn = Left(zDataIn, iStart - 1)
      Else
        zDataIn = Mid(zDataIn, 1, iStart - 1) & _
                  Right(zDataIn, iLen - iEnd)
      End If
    End If
  Loop

  StripHTML = zDataIn

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind paying US$99, there is [Aivosto RegExpr](http://www.aivosto.com/regexpr.html).  Apparently this is a pure VBA solution, that should run on both PC and Mac VBA.

Alternatively, write separate solutions for both PC and Mac, then use [compiler directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264614.aspx) to separate which bit of code runs on each platform