# Office365 Excel access to the Tools -> References menu for RegExp library

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, office365

This might sound like a simple question but I'm creating a macro in VBA that uses regular expressions. It turns out VBA doesn't inherently support regex and I need to add a reference to 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5' to gain access to regex functions in Excel.

All my searching online tells me you need to go to Tools -> References menu to add/remove references that can be used in VBA.

[The Tools -> References menu in Excel as obtained from Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0rEr.jpg)

For the life of me I can't see where the Tools -> References menu is in my Excel. I've enabled the Developers tab and it's not there.

[This is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxdFJ.png)

If it helps, I'm using Excel on Office 365 (which Wikipedia tells me is Office 2016) on a Mac. Please help me find how I can access the References menu in Excel (whether or not it can be accessed via Tools -> Menu or some other way). Thanks.

Comment: First press ALT-F11 to open the VBA editor. Tools references is in there. I don't know how different this is on a Mac though. You might also consider something called 'late binding'. This does not require Tools References and is a bit less likely to fail on another users PC. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556910/how-do-i-get-regex-support-in-excel-via-a-function-or-custom-function

Comment: Found it! After opening the VBE, the References link is actually located on the bottom-left side of the VBE screen, and not in Tools -> References as in previous versions of Excel.

Comment: Edit: I did more research and it turns out Mac versions of Excel don't have access to the VBScript.RegExp reference to use regex in VBA... hmm [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995007/how-to-develop-an-excel-macro-that-contains-regular-expressions-so-it-will-work)

Comment: Thanks very much for returning with your observations :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the Visual Basic (for applications) Editor, or VBE. On the Developers tab, look for "Visual Basic". It should be the left-most item.

Or, you can press Alt-F11.

The VBE is where you'll find the Tools menu, and the References submenu.

Comment: Found it! After pressing Alt-F11 and opening the VBE, the References window can be opened by clicking on the link in the bottom-left corner, and not by going to Tools -> References as in previous versions of Excel. [Image of references menu in Excel 365](http://imgur.com/a/IfRZE)

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the Visual Basic editor.  On the ribbon in Excel, select Developer, then Visual Basic.  This will open the VBA interface in a separate window.  On this new window, you should see the Tools -> References option.