# VBA excel Office 2016 Mac - Tools References not available

Tags: vba, macos, excel

I cannot find the tools references button in my Exel VBA Editor (Office 2016 for Mac). It is supposed to be in the corner down left as marked below.
Also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756114/office365-excel-access-to-the-tools-references-menu-for-regexp-library).

I googled for almost two hours now. Any suggestions?

**Note: It's different to Office for Windows!**

[image: Screenshot of VBA Editor Excel 2016]

Comment: I'll ask the dumb questions (that I would ask Windows users too) ... (a) Are you sure the bottom of your VBE window isn't below the bottom of the screen, i.e. is the VBE window maximised?  (b) Can you drag the bottom line (about the middle of your red rectangle) up to expose more area for the bit below that line? (Not sure whether that is even a Mac thing, or whether Macs do things differently than Windows, but may as well ask.)

Comment: :D well, thanks for those dumb questions. Just to be sure I double checked, and... thats not it.

Comment: Sometimes its the simple things that trip us up, so I figured it was worth asking. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the tools menu - top of the monitor when you have the VB editor open.